# Python -- how to plot calculated number on chart without properties detail

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a simple chart and adding a number taken from a DataFrame, via plot.text(). The number is plotting as intended, but detail of its properties are also being displayed. I would like to suppress the display of properties and plot just the number.

The following code reproduces the issue.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
%matplotlib inline

rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
index = np.arange(8)

df = DataFrame(rand.randn(8, 1), index=index, columns=list('A'))

df['date'] = date_range('1/1/2014', periods=8)

print df

   A       date
0  1.624345 2014-01-01
1 -0.611756 2014-01-02
2 -0.528172 2014-01-03
3 -1.072969 2014-01-04
4  0.865408 2014-01-05
5 -2.301539 2014-01-06
6  1.744812 2014-01-07
7 -0.761207 2014-01-08


df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = ['1'], columns=['example'])
df2['example'] = 1.436792
print df2

example
1  1.436792

fig, ax = plot.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
df.plot(x='date', y='A')

plot.text(0.05, 0.95, df2['example'],
     horizontalalignment='left',
     verticalalignment='center',
     transform = ax.transAxes)
```

The plot is showing index, name and dtype data along with the example number. Can anybody show how to suppress this detail and just plot the number? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just plot with the DataFrame values:

```
plot.text(0.05, 0.95, df2['example'].values,
     horizontalalignment='left',
     verticalalignment='center',
     transform = ax.transAxes)
```

Or just set `visible=True` to hide everything:

```
plot.text(0.05, 0.95, df2['example'],
     horizontalalignment='left',
     verticalalignment='center',
     transform = ax.transAxes, visible=False)
```

Comment: not a prob. I also added another approach in case you want to hide everything, just set `visible=False` flag